# How to code yes/no function for discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to code a function in which the bot sends the message 'happiness reloaded' when the user answers `Y`, or else it sends the message good night if the user answers `N`. I have tried to run this code, which replies to 'hi' but after that, when I type in Y or N, the bot cannot reply. My code example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  # if message.content.startswith('$inspire'):
  #   quote = get_quote()
  #   await message.channel.send(quote)

  if message.content.startswith('hi'): # Delete this after testing
    await message.channel.send('Congratulations! Your Disgotchi is hatched! (Play around? : Y/N)')
    if message.content.includes('y', 'Y'):
      await message.channel.send('Happiness reloaded! (　＾Θ＾)❤️')
    elif message.content.includes('n', 'N'):
      await message.channel.send('I will go to bed, good night!')
```

Answer (score -2):

should do what you want
all you have to do is store the ids outside the callback, expecting another message in same callback is useles as message newer changes

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
bot = Bot(command_prefix='$')

y_users = set() # set is best for this

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'hi':
        await message.channel.send('Congratulations! Your Disgotchi is hatched! (Play around? : Y/N)')
        y_users.add(message.author.id) # saving the id
    # checking if id is in set which means user sent hello previously
    elif (message.content.startswith('y', 'Y') and message.author.id in y_users):
        await message.channel.send('Happiness reloaded! (　＾Θ＾)❤️')
        y_users.remove(message.author.id)
    elif (message.content.startswith('n', 'N') and message.author.id in y_users):
      await message.channel.send('I will go to bed, good night!')
      y_users.remove(message.author.id)

bot.run("token")
```

please mark it as correct solution if it does what you want

Comment: You use the [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) method for these kind of things, this is a bad solution